# In the Windows / Active Directory world what is a privilege, and how does that differ from permissions?

Tags: active-directory, permissions

I just realized there's a difference between these two after I had to [change a privilege](https://superuser.com/a/1095130/2293) to change *permissions* on a folder (and then set them back again).

P.S. If this is a stupid question, I apologize I'm still figuring alot of these things out.

Comment: I found this list of privilege constants: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concerning Active Directory, a privilege is "what you can do" such as **impersonate a client after authentication** or concerning Windows itself **Change the system time**.

A permission is an access control applied to objects such as the file system, registry, and Active Directory objects like groups and users. The Access Control Lists grant users and/or groups the ability perform various operations on the object. For example, an object such as a Folder has an Access Control List for users to Read the contents of the folder, but not to Edit or Delete.

To show the difference between the two: A Folder may have the permission denying Admins Read and Write access to the folder, leaving Admins unable to access the Folder. However, since Admins have the user right (privilege) **Take ownership of files or other objects,** the Admin can simply take ownership of the Folder, then change the Folder's ACL to give Administrators Read and Write permissions of the Folder.

Comment: When you say Admins, do you mean (domain admins xor local admins) or both?

Comment: Both. My example was, in my mind, on a local machine, but yeah both. Local Admins' scope of privilege is locally - restricted to the computer, while domain admins' scope of privilege is the domain.

Answer (score 7):

A privilege (or user right) governs what you can do (logon interactively, logon remotely, etc.).

A permission governs what you can access (files, folders, objects, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

[These](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221963(v=ws.11).aspx) are the privileges. You already know what permissions are.

If you think about it , there isn't a distinct line between them tho. "Allow log on locally" is a privilege , but, when you add a user there, you're just giving them permission to log on to that computer. Again, you can say that permissions are given on resources, but, "computer" is also a resource in my example above.

Instead of trying to understand what they are called, you should learn the list of privileges from the web page I linked above. That is the whole list and that will help you solve your problems.